# Deploying ERC20 emblem

Tags: wallets, exchanges

When Bitcoin and Ethereum initially launched they had emblematic figures such as a B and a prysm to represent the token on exchanges and wallets e.g. MetaMask. Does one have to use JavaScript to plugin the image to each exchange?? I would like to know

Answer (score 1):

They were just images drawn by someone.

Comment: I'm deploying my own token soon , do you know how to add an emblem?

Comment: Call our artist and make a PNG file.